# How to deploy Ganttlab in a path different than "/"

Tags: node.js, gitlab, yarnpkg, vue-cli

I am installing Ganttlab locally and I want to be able to use it in https://[mygitlabserver]/ganttlab/. The configuration and build process are pretty straightforward. However, I noticed that some files like "dist/index.html" and "dist/js/app.xxxxxx.js" have been built with "/" as the default path, resulting in a lot of 302's or 404's.

Is there a way I can configure this path before the build:webapp?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The webapp uses [vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/).
So create a vue config file: `packages/ganttlab-adapter-webapp/vue.config.json`

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: './'
}
```

The code above will make all paths relative.
Depending on you setup you can also set the path explicit `publicPath: '/ganttlab/'`

For more info: [github.com/ganttlab/ganttlab download and install](https://gitlab.com/ganttlab/ganttlab/-/blob/master/docs/download-and-install.md)